# A semilinear second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y''+\dfrac{1}{x}y'-\dfrac{\sin y\cos y}{x^2}=0$, $y(0)=0$ and $y(x)>0$ for all $x>0$.

For this problem I know that the solution $y=\arccos\dfrac{c^2-x^2}{c^2+x^2}$ for arbitrary constant $c>0$ fits the equation and initial values. But I don't know how to get such an solution and the uniqueness.

I tried to change the variables. $u=\cos y$, and substitute denote $y$ by $\arccos u$. But it will produce a term like $u_x^2$ and that's where I get stuck.  Also I tried to combine the first two terms by $(xy')'$ after multiply $x$ on both sides. Then let $u=xy'$. Then one will end up with an equation like $u''+\dfrac {1}{x}u'-\dfrac {1}{x^2}u^3=0$ which is still hard for me.

As for the uniqueness this certainly does not fit the theory for linear second ODE and I'm not sure about the uniqueness theory of nonlinear second ODE.

Looking forward to any kind of advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$y''+\dfrac{1}{x}y'-\dfrac{\sin y\cos y}{x^2}=0$$
$$2x^2y''y'+2xy'^2=2\sin(y)\cos(y) y'$$
$$\big( x^2 y'^2 \big)'=2\sin(y)\cos(y) y'$$
$$x^2 y'^2=\sin^2(y)+constant$$
With $y(0)=0$ :
$$x^2 y'^2=\sin^2(y)$$
I let you continue...

Comment: ELEGANT!You are genius